Image/Video slider with frequently changing dataset
(Most definitely a duplicate but couldn't find the related post)
I'm attempting to create an image/videoslider in Android with Java language.
The dataset would be pulled from the local public directory and would change on random times
(1min, 30 sec, purely random...)
(I.e. Some images might get deleted and newer ones will be added.)
What would be the most suitable way to implement this?
ViewPager2?
RecyclerView for better control?
ViewFlipper for simplicity?
Notes:

I'll have to display videos in their full length before changing the displayed media
MUST be completely seamless

